# Why my GUILayout is outside my FoldoutHeaderGroup ? Unity editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I'm a Unity  tools developer and i want to put a `GUILayout.Label(" title ")` inside a `FoldoutHeaderGroup` so i did that :

```cs
    using UnityEditor;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class tesdtEditor : EditorWindow
    {
        private bool showWindowFoldOut;

        [MenuItem("test")]
        public static void ShowWindow()
        {
            EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(tesdtEditor));
        }

        public void OnGUI()
        {
            showWindowFoldOut = EditorGUILayout.BeginFoldoutHeaderGroup(showWindowFoldOut, "foldout Name");

            GUILayout.Label("title");

            EditorGUILayout.EndFoldoutHeaderGroup();
        }
    }
```

But it's not in my FoldoutHeaderGroup ([Screen of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKxhR.png))

I can't see where I'm mistaken, can someone guide me through ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to check the

```
if(showWindowFoldOut)
{
    EditorGUI.indentLevel++;

    GUILayout.Label("title");

    EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
}
```

See example in [`EditorGUILayout.BeginFoldoutHeaderGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.BeginFoldoutHeaderGroup.html).

---

Tbh besides the different styling I didn't understand so far what the difference is between that and a simple [`EditorGUILayout.Foldout`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Foldout.html).